# How to execute scripts automatically on SQL Express instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Servers are SQL Express - about 160 instances. What I need is to execute various scripts(clean tables, backups etc.) on them automatically several times a day. I do not want to use standard Windows Scheduler, as it sometimes just doesn't work. 
I am looking for a solution maybe free maybe not.
Free preferably.

Comment: Express doesn't come with Agent, which is what you'd normally use, so your options are Batch Scripts or something similar external to SQL Server. Side note, this question will undoubtedly be closed because it isn't about programming so you may want to check our dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question is what tool to use to start this external

Comment: Yes... but it's opinion based and off topic. See #4 here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Your questions should be MCVE, which you can read about here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: IMO you should preferebly focus on solving problem you descibed as "Windows Scheduler sometimes just doesn't work" instead of searching for workarounds. Batches launched from Windows Scheduler are preferable choice. If there is some problem with them, work on identifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to run a batch script to get things done.

For the benefit of all, here's a Delete.bat

```
ECHO Executing Job
ECHO.
PAUSE
sqlcmd -S "london-sql\sqlexpress" -E -Q "exec London.dbo.DeleteAll"
ECHO Job execution Completed
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

(‘london-sql\sqlexpress’ is the name of the server)

The Load.dat is almost identical, except '"exec London.dbo.LoadAll"'

Call the batch script with Windows Scheduler.

http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/all/